# Correlation between Likert scale question and binary question?

Tags: regression, correlation, r-squared, likert, excel

I am writing a report and I need to find correlation between question: how much do you trust banks (from 1-I dont trust them at all and 5-i trust them completely) and question: are you a member of credit union? (answers: "yes" and "no")

1. Can I make regression with data analysis in excel, see the p-value and $R^2$ or I need to do something else?
2. How can I calculate a correlation between two "yes" and "no" questions? Can I also make regression or sholud I do something else?
3. How can I correlate? What is your level of education? (From 0-high school to 3-phD) and "yes" and "no" question?